ASUS laptop not starting: battery LED blinking green twice then pause
ASUS laptop GL552V not starting. Power LED 'on', Caps lock LED 'on', fan working, battery LED blinking green twice then pause... blinking green twice again (one-second interval) then pause, etc, etc... Screen is black. Any idea how to make it start, Thanks!

@Gantendo: Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Okay, if someone comes here and has the same problem, here is the solution we found: open the laptop and clean/dust the memory card.

Thanks for your help @Gantendo

Flashing battery LED is usually a notification of a charging problem.

Check if the battery feels hot. Charging is stopped if it's overheating.

Remove the battery when shut down and see if the power adapter alone
can successfully start the laptop. If not, then the problem might be
with it.

If you gently wiggle the power adapter plug, does it change behavior?

If none of the above has any effect, probably the battery needs
to be replaced. Some laptop models require a functional battery
in order to startup.

If you're unsure, bring the laptop to a professional repair service.


